# SELinux: restorecon wont change context to httpd_sys_content_t

Tags: linux, selinux

I need to use Puppeteer on a Centos 7.4.1708 system but when I have SELinux set to Enforcing I'm getting AVC errors.

If I run `sudo cat /var/log/messages` I get:

```
SELinux is preventing /var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-549031/chrome-linux/chrome from search access on the directory /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset.

*****  Plugin restorecon_source (99.5 confidence) suggests   *****************

If you want to fix the label.
/var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-549031/chrome-linux/chrome default label should be httpd_sys_content_t.    
Then you can run restorecon.    
Do    
# /sbin/restorecon -v /var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-549031/chrome-linux/chrome
```

This same message appears maybe 6 or 7 times.

When I try to do the above though, restorecon won't set the context of the file.

Set policy (as root):
`semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t '/var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-549031/chrome-linux/chrome'`

Check policy:
`matchpathcon /var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-549031/chrome-linux/chrome`
Shows:
`/var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-549031/chrome-linux/chrome   system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0`

That looks good, but then...
Set new context to file:
`/sbin/restorecon -v /var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-549031/chrome-linux/chrome`

`restorecon` fails to work. I don't get any errors from it even if I use `-vv`.
I have also tried to force `restorecon` with `-F` but that doesn't work either.

Here's the files current context:
`ls -Z /var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-549031/chrome-linux/chrome`
Shows:
`-rwxrwxrwx. root root system_u:object_r:nfs_t:s0       /var/www/html/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-549031/chrome-linux/chrome`

The current context is `nfs_t` because I use synced folders with `nfs` in Vagrant running virtual box. I can't change to smb because it doesn't sync both ways using a Windows host.

Any ideas on how I can fix this issue? I've been at it for nearly two days now.

Note: If I set SELinux to Permissive then Puppeteer/Chromium runs without issue.

Thanks :)

Edit: I also should mention I have `httpd_use_nfs` set to `on`.

Here's a pastebin of all my SELinux booleans.

[SELinux booleans](https://pastebin.com/5HsR8JbQ)

Edit 2:

Using the advice of @HBruijn I try to mount with defined context, but receive error.

AS root command:
`mount 10.0.0.1:/C/Users/Lee/Desktop/www /var/www -o context="system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0"`

Error:
`mount.nfs: requested NFS version or transport protocol is not supported`

Server `10.0.0.1` is my private server setup in `vagrantfile`.
`config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.0.0"`

The export path is the same path Vagrant uses when it mounts a folder on `vagrant up` e.g `10.0.0.1:/C/path/to/directory`.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to solve the problem from the wrong end, have you considered giving your webserver access to NFS shares instead with:

```
setsebool -P httpd_use_nfs=1
```

**EDIT** Based on your comment that you running VirtualBox on Windows:

I *think* that your Windows host does not support labeling and then the client (your CentOS) assigns a default security policy as `nfs_t`.

You may need to set your preferred security context as a mount option to override that default (in the mount command or /etc/fstab) :

```
# mount server:/export /var/www/html -o  context="system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0"
```

See [the RHEL 6 manual](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/sect-security-enhanced_linux-working_with_selinux-mounting_file_systems)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I already have `httpd_use_nfs --> on`. I'll edit the OP.

Comment: I've added a pastebin of all my other SELinux booleans.

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that you are running VirtualBox on Windows with a CentOS guest OS?

Comment: Yes, thats correct. Using the winnfsd plugin to get nfs working in windows.

Comment: When I run that as root I get this error: 
`mount.nfs: Failed to resolve server server: Name or service not known
mount.nfs: Operation already in progress`

Comment: You'll need to change the servername and paths from `server:/export /var/www/html` to whatever is relevant for your current setup

Comment: Where would I export from if my ` /var/www/html` files are from host OS?? Would I need to sync host OS folder with a guest folder e.g `/fromhost/www/html` then use that path as the export path. `mount server:/fromhost/www/html /var/www/html -o  context="system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0"`

Comment: Using mount is not working for some reason. Please see Edit 2 in the OP. Getting error `mount.nfs: requested NFS version or transport protocol is not supported`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting below options with mount. They worked for me in CIFS mount. Might work on nfs too.
uid=
gid=
file_mode=
dir_mode=
fscontext=